# Node.js test with expresso

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, expresso

I tried to use [expresso](http://visionmedia.github.io/expresso/) to test my project.
I have installed it with command

```
sudo npm install --save expresso
```

and it worked for me.
Than I decided to test it in created `test.js` file with code

```
var assert = require('assert');
assert.equal(6, 'foobar'.length);
```

I run it with command `expresso ./test.js` as was written in example
But I have got result

```
No command 'expresso' found, did you mean:
Command 'extresso' from package 'icoutils' (universe)
Command 'express' from package 'node-express' (universe)
expresso: command not found
```

Can anyone help me, please? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer. I should install `expresso` globally

```
sudo npm install -g expresso
```

I have found good example [here](http://51elliot.blogspot.com/2011/07/simple-introduction-to-tdd-with.html)